# How to add pages without put addViewController for every page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was studing about the spring framework, and folowing some tutorials on the internet, and then I found this:

```
    package control;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

    @Configuration
    public class MVCController implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
              registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
              registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
              registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
              registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        }

    }
```

So my doubts is:

- *How can I put more pages without put new lines to add View Controllers to every page?*
- *There is some way to put some generic controller to pages that I not going to make some processing? (e.g. some static page)*

I'm using the spring 5 and Java JRE 1.8.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you set up a `ViewResolver` bean in your `config class`, for example, a common one around is like this:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}
```

After this you can create controller classes with the `@Controller` annotation within which you will assign `@RequestMapping` annotation that will listen to the destination assigned.

For example,

```
@Controller
public class yourCustomController {

//this will be your home page
@RequestMapping(value ="/")
public String showHomePage(){
//the return statement will look in the path defined in the view resolver and add the .jsp suffix ( so it will display file "/web-inf/view/my-home-page.jsp" )
  return "my-home-page";
}
}
```

You can also assign controllers to certain paths, e.g.,
`@Controller(value="/blog")` all the controllers `@RequestMappings` will be mapped to `root/blog/**`.

Comment: But I really need to create a new class and put a new 'addViewController' on *every page*? So, if I create 20 pages, and just 5 need controllers, and the others are static text for every one read, I really need to create 20 controller classes?

Comment: The first code is to be put in your config file. This can be `@Java annotated` or `XML` config. 

Then you can have as many pages in a controller as you wish.